# How to setup a Mac to build iOS apps using Xamarin.Forms with VS2017?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I have Visual Studio 2017 on a Windows computer with Xamarin installed. I know that I need to connect to a Mac in order to build iOS apps. I don't, however, know how to set up the Mac in order to do that. I've found some information on the web. However, at least some of it seems to be outdated. For example - I'm told to use Xamarin Studio. Which seems to have been superseded by VS. Also, it seems that VS2017 can do more by itself than previous versions of VS.

So, What do I need on the Mac, when using VS2017, in order to build Xamarin.Forms apps for iOS?

Comment: this guide should still apply, although you need to replace XS with VSMac: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/

Comment: @Jason Thanks. Will that mean I'll also not need to install the Xamarin.iOS SDK separately?

Comment: the VSMac installer should do it for you

Comment: @Jason Thanks. Your comments seem to be the answer. (I'm assuming you're correct, of course). You can transform them into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install Xcode and at least start it once and accept the EULA. Then you also need to install Visual Studio for Mac, which will pull in all requirements for you, as mentioned in the comments, [this guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/) should still get you a long way there, just replace Xamarin Studio with Visual Studio for Mac.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not accepting yet, in case Jason posts his own answer.